# google.script.run stopped working in my web application

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, typeerror

my google web app has been running since months without issues.
Today I suddenly get the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined".

Nothing was changed in the code

Comment: Create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been found in the meanwhile.

Apparently, on some PC's it was working, on others it wasn't.
After clearing the browsing history (and cookies) on the PC, all was working again.